# Android: UI Collaboration (Jenkins+Spoon+?)

Tags: android, user-interface, jenkins, robotium, spoon

I really like the idea of automated testing for Android.
I've tried Spoon, which gives great results for previewing current state of UI on different devices.
The problem is how to effectively share it with the team (developers/UI/UX).
What I want to have is: build server(Jenkins) triggers Robotium+Spoon test, which takes screenshots of each screen, then the build server publishes results of Spoon to some web-app(?), where we can see all the Spoon reports grouped by date and where we can leave comments on each of the screenshot.
**What web-app will fit my needs?**

Comment: Interested in commercial solutions?

Comment: Sure. I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: I can recommend Testdroid, however it doesn't support Spoon. Anyway you can integrate it with Jenkins and run Robotium, UIAutomator, Calabash etc. Unfortunately Spoon is not at the list of supported frameworks yet.

Comment: Nice. It's third-party service, right? I would like to install the web-app behind our corp firewall, like internal resource. Should I write small java-based web-app + DB, so I'll be able to add comments (it's basically all I need)? Is there any template for this kind of web-app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I currently just use Jenkins. I have a script execute spoon and then I pointed Jenkins to where spoon outputs the results and presto! We now have automated test results attached to every build. Coupled with the screenshots this has impressed my managers and made debugging a much easier process. The last bonus is that it's all FREE! [image]

Comment: It's perfect! Quick and easy to implement. Is there a way to add comments to each screenshot?

Comment: I can't think of an easy or pre-constructed solution to that one... Sounds like a fun weekend project though... :D

Comment: @psionicNinja Can you share that script?

Answer (score 0):

Note the selected answer of the HTML Publisher extension no longer works due to security changes in jenkins.  Starting in jenkins versions 1.625.3 and 1.641 restrictions were added to block javascript which makes it more limited in display and almost useless